# How to apply correctly the margins on elements in responsive design?

Tags: css

I am working on a sticky add to cart box on this URL: https://www.tresor-ethnique.com/collections/africain/products/pendentif-multi-couche-africain

Basically I want the image on the left to have a 5% margin, and the button on the right to have a 5% margin as well

And I setup max width as 1550px

[image]

So here is my code:

```
.sticky_addcart_wrapper {
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    max-width: 1550px;
}
```

It does exactly what I want on a 1920px wide desktop screen

But if I reduce the width of my window, I see that **the add to cart button goes slightly out of the window** (and the right margin is then completely gone)

[image]

The left side behaves like I would like (it keeps the left margin)

Maybe I have written something wrong for right side behavior?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wrapper has no defined width, and is still respecting the `max-width` of `1550px` as you shrink your screen size. It may work as desired if you just add a width to the wrapper:

```
.sticky_addcart_wrapper {
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1550px;
}
```

Comment: shiiit that was simple, I had actually left width as 100% but didn't realize it was adding with my 10%, thank you!

Comment: @Pascal no problem happy to help!